# How can I manage to unify multiple animations of sliding wagon doors in single animation

Tags: animation

Please help me))Here I find solutions for armature animation.But I have to union animations of eight separate sliding doors of a wagon in one single animation.I need to export it in GLTF format and then assign one single animation in external graphic engine

[image]